# Do I have to install Developer Tools to get the "make" command working in OS X?

Tags: macos, make

I'm pretty new to OS X and wish to get the "make" command working but dont fancy paying $99 to apple for developer tools. Is there another (free) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4 is available on the Mac App Store for $5. I wouldn't be surprised if Fink, MacPorts, or Homebrew (or all 3) had `make` binaries you could use.

Comment: You need to have Xcode installed to use Fink, MacPorts, and Homebrew.

Comment: It's been a long time since I had Fink installed, so I'd forgotten. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can still get Xcode 3 for free by [registering as Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/) without purchasing any of the iOS or Mac Developer Program options.